# Mirror Api INSERT Timeline subscriptions

Tags: google-mirror-api, google-gdk

I have a paginated card in a bundle that launches an immersion.

Is there any way to:

1. Figure out the itemId of that card?
2. Update that card from the immersion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**On  Mirror API side:**
The notification about a timeline item has been performed some action on is sent in one of those two cases:

1. this is a card created by the same application and user perform any the action on it (i.e. reply)
2. this is a card from another app but user share it to contact that represent your glassware

The notification contain the timeline item id and action was taken by user

If this is time line item published by your Mirror API application - you can update it using [update action](https://developers.google.com/glass/v1/reference/timeline/update)

**If this is a card created by your GDK app** - you can update it using [TimelineMnager.update(long id, Card card)](https://developers.google.com/glass/develop/gdk/reference/com/google/android/glass/timeline/TimelineManager#update%28long,%20com.google.android.glass.app.Card%29)